# Creating hosts list in order to pass to Python script in Ansible playbook

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to run an Ansible playbook that will gather all the hosts (or per group) to a list that next I'll pass as an argument to a Python script.
I tried tons of things but at the end only the current host is passed to the script.

```
ansible 2.4.2.0
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

## Some examples:

---

### My simple hosts file:

```
[cluster_1]
100.126.247.167 corename=paas-om-core1 vip=1.1.1.1
100.126.246.237 vip=1.1.1.1
100.126.246.201
```

---

```
---
 - hosts: all
   become: yes
   become_user: root
   vars:
     ips: []
   tasks:
     - name: create list
       set_fact:
          ips: []

     - name: append to list
       set_fact:
         ips: "{{ ips  }} + [ '{{ inventory_hostname  }}' ]"

     - debug:
         var: "{{ ips }}"
```

## Result:

```
...
TASK [append to list] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [100.126.247.167] => {"ansible_facts": {"ips": ["100.126.247.167"]}, "changed": false}
ok: [100.126.246.237] => {"ansible_facts": {"ips": ["100.126.246.237"]}, "changed": false}
ok: [100.126.246.201] => {"ansible_facts": {"ips": ["100.126.246.201"]}, "changed": false}

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [100.126.247.167] => {
    "<type 'list'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
ok: [100.126.246.237] => {
    "<type 'list'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
ok: [100.126.246.201] => {
    "<type 'list'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

---

### Example 2:

```
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
         - "{{ groups['all'] }}"
    when: corename is defined  /*I want it run only on one defined host */
    register: host_list
  - debug:
      var: host_list

  - debug:
      var: item.item
    with_items: "{{ host_list.results }}"
    register: items

 - debug:
     var: items
 - script: "/home/oded/Sandbox/ansible/pyScript/test.py {{ host_list  }}"
   when: corename is defined
 - script: "/home/oded/Sandbox/ansible/pyScript/test.py {{host_list.results}}"
   when: corename is defined
 - script: "/home/oded/Sandbox/ansible/pyScript/test.py {{ items  }}"
   when: corename is defined
```

### test.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import sys
print ( sys.argv)
```

### Results:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skip ...
ok: [100.126.247.167] => (item=100.126.247.167) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": "100.126.247.167",
    "msg": "100.126.247.167"
}
ok: [100.126.247.167] => (item=100.126.246.237) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": "100.126.246.237",
    "msg": "100.126.246.237"
}
ok: [100.126.247.167] => (item=100.126.246.201) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": "100.126.246.201",
    "msg": "100.126.246.201"
}

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [100.126.247.167] => {
    "host_list": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "100.126.247.167",
                "msg": "100.126.247.167"
            },
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "100.126.246.237",
                "msg": "100.126.246.237"
            },
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "100.126.246.201",
                "msg": "100.126.246.201"
            }
        ]
    }
}
ok: [100.126.246.237] => {
    "host_list": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": false,
                "item": "100.126.247.167",
                "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
                "skipped": true
            },
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": false,
                "item": "100.126.246.237",
                "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
                "skipped": true
            },
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "changed": false,
                "item": "100.126.246.201",
                "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
                "skipped": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
skip ...

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [100.126.247.167] => (item={'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, 'item': u'100.126.247.167', '_ansible_item_result': True, 'failed': False, 'msg': u'100.126.247.167', '_ansible_verbose_always': True, '_ansible_ignore_errors': None}) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "item": "100.126.247.167",
        "msg": "100.126.247.167"
    },
    "item.item": "100.126.247.167"
}
ok: [100.126.247.167] => (item={'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, 'item': u'100.126.246.237', '_ansible_item_result': True, 'failed': False, 'msg': u'100.126.246.237', '_ansible_verbose_always': True, '_ansible_ignore_errors': None}) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "item": "100.126.246.237",
        "msg": "100.126.246.237"
    },
    "item.item": "100.126.246.237"
}
ok: [100.126.247.167] => (item={'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, 'item': u'100.126.246.201', '_ansible_item_result': True, 'failed': False, 'msg': u'100.126.246.201', '_ansible_verbose_always': True, '_ansible_ignore_errors': None}) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "item": "100.126.246.201",
        "msg": "100.126.246.201"
    },
    "item.item": "100.126.246.201"
}
skip ...

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [100.126.247.167] => {
    "items": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": {
                    "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                    "_ansible_item_result": true,
                    "_ansible_no_log": false,
                    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
                    "changed": false,
                    "failed": false,
                    "item": "100.126.247.167",
                    "msg": "100.126.247.167"
                },
                "item.item": "100.126.247.167"
            },
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": {
                    "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                    "_ansible_item_result": true,
                    "_ansible_no_log": false,
                    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
                    "changed": false,
                    "failed": false,
                    "item": "100.126.246.237",
                    "msg": "100.126.246.237"
                },
                "item.item": "100.126.246.237"
            },
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": {
                    "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                    "_ansible_item_result": true,
                    "_ansible_no_log": false,
                    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
                    "changed": false,
                    "failed": false,
                    "item": "100.126.246.201",
                    "msg": "100.126.246.201"
                },
                "item.item": "100.126.246.201"
            }
        ]
    }
}
skip ...

TASK [script] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [100.126.246.237] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
skipping: [100.126.246.201] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
changed: [100.126.247.167] => {"changed": true, "rc": 0, "stderr": "Shared connection to 100.126.247.167 closed.\r\n", "stdout": "{msg:\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["{msg:"]}

TASK [script] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [100.126.246.237] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
skipping: [100.126.246.201] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
changed: [100.126.247.167] => {"changed": true, "rc": 0, "stderr": "Shared connection to 100.126.247.167 closed.\r\n", "stdout": "[{changed:\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["[{changed:"]}

TASK [script] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [100.126.246.237] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
skipping: [100.126.246.201] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
changed: [100.126.247.167] => {"changed": true, "rc": 0, "stderr": "Shared connection to 100.126.247.167 closed.\r\n", "stdout": "{msg:\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["{msg:"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, all you want is this single task:

```
- script: "/home/oded/Sandbox/ansible/pyScript/test.py {{ groups['all'] | join(' ')  }}"
  when: corename is defined
```

It will pass the inventory names, members of the `all` group, as space-separated arguments to the script.

Add quotes around, if you need.

---

It's hard to comment on all the mistakes in the code you posted...

- Semantic error in the first method: `var: "{{ ips }}"` should be `var: ips`.
- Expectation of facts having a common value across all hosts (while a fact holds a different value on each distinct host).
- Misuse of register with `debug` in the second method. That’s what `set_fact` is for.
- Trying to pass a Python object as a command line argument.
- Using `item` outside of loops.

Comment: I'm new to ansible. Can you recommend a good tutorials, to broaden my knowledge? 10X

Comment: Is it possible to send the params that relate to the hosts as well (corename=xxx)?                                                                             [cluster_1]
100.126.247.167 corename=paas-om-core1 vip=1.1.1.1